# Arxiv Empty Bibliographic data

Tags: citations, arxiv, latex

I have uploaded a paper to arxiv. It has several citations / references.

However, when I look at the Bibliographic data, it is shown as empty..

Any hints of what could be wrong?

[image]

Comment: Where are you looking at the "biliographic data"?  That's not an arxiv.org page image.  Moreover, it is unclear whether you are looking for it to show citations to or from your manuscript.

Comment: In addition, how long has the paper been up (public) on the arXiv? Separate databases (like the NASA ADS) will generally take a day or more to update their listings.

Comment: @Buzz Yes, this is an screenshot from Arxiv. Recent papers have Semantic Scholar enabled.

Comment: @Anyon The paper has been there for a couple of weeks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found some preprints that happened to show this bibliographic data section, e.g. [1805.02262](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02262). Clicking the [What is Bibex?](https://labs.arxiv.org/projects/bibexplorer) link, I note that the current version of the arXiv Bibliographic Explorer is 0.1, from September this year. In addition, they refer to this functionality as a project. Hence, I think you're looking at a somewhat experimental feature, still in development. Most likely then, this feature simply hasn't been able to extract the data it needs, for whatever reason. You could use the "report data issues" link to send them a feedback email to help the development forward.